# Why does an impact driver have some 'wobble'?

Tags: screws

I noticed how any impact I use has a little 'wobble' in the bit. Really noticeable in a long Philips or a spade bit. I own a Ryobi, but I have used Rigid, Bosch, and Dewalt. Every one with the same thing. Is this meant to be? Will it cause problems when driving screws into my projects?

Comment: Not strictly woodworking related, this is the sort of Question probably better asked in another SE.

Comment: Are you predrilling when you use your impact driver?

Comment: @rob Yes I do. My regular drill does the drilling then I use the impact for screwing. It works better for me. And in many cases, can go faster.

Comment: @Graphus Impact drivers are used in woodworking, and questions about tools are on-topic here, so I think it can be left open. I do agree that it might be better for another stack, though.

Comment: The bigger issue is there are two separate questions here - the wobble and a more general comparison of impact driver vs drill. I've edited the question to be specific to the wobble, so if you want to ask the other part @Ljk2000, you should ask a separate question

Comment: I loath Philips, I have abandoned Philips for Torx,

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to address the "what advantage would there be over a regular drill" part of the question first.

Impact drivers are much better at driving fasteners, drills are much better at drilling.  (Hence the different names...)

When you're drilling you want a thin, continuous cut.  This means that you normally don't need a ton of torque, but you want it continuously.  Drills are built to do this because they just turn at full torque the whole time.

With a fastener you don't really care if you stop and start, but you want as much torque as possible.  So an impact driver applies more torque, but it does it intermittently (hence the "clicking" when you use it.)  This also has the added benefit of not causing "reaction" torque, when a drill binds up and tries to twist your arm.  So you can apply a lot more torque with an impact than you ever could with a drill.

All that said, since an impact is intended to be used with fasteners it doesn't really matter if it wobbles.  You're normally using it on something that isn't prone to walking around like a twist drill bit does.

Comment: now that I think of it I did have all the fun with the drill twisting my arm. Which is one of the big things I love about the impact, no twisting.

Comment: Additionally, an impact driver typically has a hex or square drive for bits that has high strength and a quick change. The wobble is not important and is a side effect of that design. A drill cannot wobble and has to accommodate many sizes of drill bits, and thus has an adjustable chuck.

Comment: The impact also applies that torque intermittently, or "pulsed" between each hammer blow (yes, there's a little hammer inside :) which allows the bit to re-seat in the screw head. This is why bits and screw heads, Phillips in particular, last much longer with an impact driver. They don't have the same tendency to "cam-out" that they do with a drill-driver.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience impact drivers have a short head with a short hex-shaped recess to receive bits and drivers, where a drill has a chuck with a much firmer grip on bits. Hence the greater wobble factor using the impact driver. An impact driver is great for rough framing where I am not predrilling for screws, but I do not use it on better quality woodworking projects. For me it is like the difference between a broad heavy masonry chisel and fine woodworking one.  Different tools for different applications.

Answer (score 0):

All impact drivers have deliberate  nose wobble so the bit centres itself in the screw used eg square , philips, flat etc

Comment: Well, it's deliberate in that the impact movement requires movement in multiple axis, which naturally leads to this sort of wobble to some tolerance. You should produce some evidence that this is a specifically engineered feature for interacting with fasteners. Because if that is what you are suggesting, I don't think this is correct.

Answer (score -2):

An impact driver is primary a single purpose tool for installing or removing threaded fasteners, at this it is very good. Much less striped heads or broken screws, and less torque on your wrists.
In short if you drive screws you need one. Ditto to most of what was said above but I use mine for all screws.

Comment: This does not answer the question.